# How to escape quotes when setting a javascript string to the value propagated from a Django variable?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm propagating several variables to my template, some of which are strings that I want to use and manipulate through javascript.  I'm setting this value as such:

```
var venue_toc = "{{terms_and_conditions}}";
```

`terms_and_conditions` is capable of having quotes in it itself, so I need to escape those in order for things to work as expected.  What is the correct way to do that when bringing values up from Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with built-in filter [escapejs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs)

```
var venue_toc = "{{terms_and_conditions|escapejs}}";
```